# QML: Lambda function works unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, qt, lambda, qml

I thought QML supported lambda functions because of JavaScript's support of anonymous functions and the fact that functions are first class objects, but they don't work how I expected.  Take this code:

```
Item {
    property var items: []

    function handler( item ) {
        console.log( item );
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        for ( var i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {
            var item = someObj.createObject();
            item.someValueChanged.connect( function() {
                handler( item ); } );

            items.push( item );
            console.log( "Adding:", item );
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: someObj

        Item {
            property bool someValue: false

            Timer {
                running: true
                onTriggered: {
                    parent.someValue = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the lambda `function() { handler( item ); }` so that when the `someObj::someValueChanged` signal is emitted the emitting item is passed to the `handler( item )` function.

I *assumed* that each loop would create a new instance of the lambda and that the `item` reference would carry the reference of the `someObj` instance created in that loop (i.e. `item` would be captured by the lambda).  But that doesn't seem to be the case as the output is:

```
qml: Adding: QQuickItem_QML_1(0x2442aa0)
qml: Adding: QQuickItem_QML_1(0x2443c00)
qml: Adding: QQuickItem_QML_1(0x2445370)
qml: QQuickItem_QML_1(0x2445370)
qml: QQuickItem_QML_1(0x2445370)
qml: QQuickItem_QML_1(0x2445370)
```

As you can see, either the whole function is being replaced on each loop or just the `item` reference, so that ultimately only the last created `someObj` is referred to.  Can someone explain to me why lambdas (if that's even what it is) don't work the way I expect?  And is this a QML issue, or a general JavaScript one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
item.someValueChanged.connect(function(capture) {
    return function() {
        handler(capture)}
}(item))
```

Intuitive, right? :D

If JS used "block scope" there would be 3 different `item`s being referenced for each loop iteration, and it would "work as expected". But with "function scope" there is only one `item` referenced, and it references its final value, thus the need to use that hack to "capture" each value in time.

Just to explain it, in case it isn't immediately obvious, the signal is connected to a handler that is arbitrated by a function which captures the parameter value at the particular time as a discrete object, which is used to feed to the handler.

Hopefully, the incipient Qt 5.12 release will remedy that with the introduction of support for `let`, a.k.a block scoped variables.

Update: I can confirm that using 5.12, it now works as expected:

```
let item = someObj.createObject(); // will produce 3 distinct obj refs
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense (for JS anyway).  Thank you!

Comment: @cmannett85 - what would happen in C++ if you try to run a lambda delayed, referencing locals of a function that has gone out of scope? Best case if it was on the stack to begin with and the stack hasn't gone to that depth afterwards and that memory is not overwritten, it might work, but most likely it will crash.

Comment: True except that in C++ you can specify what is captured _and how_.  Something that JS doesn't support (at least the version that QtQuick uses).

Comment: @ddriver I'm having a nasty crash precisely for doing that. In QML javascript, I pass an anonymous function as a slot to a signal from a  C++ object. Sometimes the signal is called after the function has gone out of scope and the system crashes (at least in iOS). You can check the question in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850030/qml-qobject-destroyed-before-being-able-to-process-a-signal/30850208)

Comment: The way captures work in javascript is the less intuitive way ever

Comment: Many thanks for this very useful answer! It explained the strange behaviour I was seeing. I've added a useful simplified version of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50454972/249239).

Answer (score 0):

[dtech's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28900786/249239) solves the problem (thanks!) but we can simplify it so that it is clearer as to what exactly is going on. The 'inner' function needs to be anonymous but there is no need for the 'outer' one to be. Using a normal function for the outer one makes the code a lot easier to understand and easier for it to be self-documenting since the function has a name. The outer function creates a signal handler so the equivalent code can be:

```
var signal_handler = create_signal_handler(item);
item.someValueChanged.connect(signal_handler);

...

function create_signal_handler(item)
{
    return function() { return handler(item); }
}
```