# QML QObject destroyed before being able to process a signal

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml, signals-slots

In QML, I'm using a C++ library that returns a QObject that does a process and emits a signal when is done. In javascript, I use the `connect` method of the signal being emitted (`success`) to attach an anonymous function that should handle the signal as the following piece of code shows:

```
var requestResponse = apiClient.execute(reqInp);
requestResponse.success.connect(function success(response) 
{
        var requestResponseJSON = JSON.parse(response.responseAsJsonString());
        this.append(response.responseAsJsonString());
});
```

My problem is that sometimes the QML item that contains this method is destroyed before the C++ code being able to complete, so when the signal is emitted, the anonymous function causes an error, because it calls methods that are undefined (in my example, the method `append`). I have some nasty crashes in iOS and I suspect that this is what might be causing it.

Is there a way of force disconnection of the signal when the object that created the function is destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

```
var requestResponse = apiClient.execute(reqInp);
function myFunction(response) 
{
        var requestResponseJSON = JSON.parse(response.responseAsJsonString());
        this.append(response.responseAsJsonString());
}
requestResponse.success.connect(myFunction);
requestResponse.destroyed.disconnect(myFunction)
```

Comment: Hi Milovidov, it seems like QML does not expose the distroyed signal. When I tried your approach, I got:    `TypeError: Cannot call method 'disconnect' of undefined`.

Comment: Also, I think that what is being destroyed is not the requestResponse object, but the Item that contains that code, in this case a ListModel QML object.

Comment: @mortadelo you can try to `disconnect` in the [`destruction`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#destruction-signal) signal handler of the sorrounding `Item`, i.e. write something like this, inside your `ListModel`:   `Component.onDestruction: { /* disconnect code here*/  }`.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo the problem is that requestResponse objects are created dynamically in several places in the item, so I don't know before hand which ones exists. I could try to keep a list of them and disconnect all signals of all of them on destroy of the item. It sounds, however, as something that Qt should do for me, doesn't it?

Comment: @mortadelo dynamically instanced objects are destroyed by the runtime, right, but you should consider destroying them yourself for the sake of perfomances, see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html).

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo I think the problem is that the anonymous javascript function attached to the signal is not being destroyed and executes even after the Item was destroyed which leads to errors

Comment: Sorry for my post, this method accepted for Qt Srcipt module, but not supported in QML. But I think, that in your case easy way to use declarative connection style, not in script. In this case any slots will be disconnected before qml item destroy.

Comment: @Milovidov the problem with declarative connections is that the `requestResponse` object does not exist before hand. It is returned by the `apiClient execute` method.