# Connect signal to intrinsic handler in JavaScript

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Take [`MenuItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-menuitem.html) as an example, normally in QML, specifying the handler for the `triggered` signal is simple:

```
MenuItem {
    onTriggered: {
        console.log("Hey");
    }
}
```

Now if I want to do the same thing, but instead to a dynamically created `MenuItem`, e.g. via `Menu.addItem()`, then what is the syntax like to connect and specify the signal handler?

I didn't expect this to work, but here is a working solution:

```
function onTriggered() {
    console.log("Hey");
}

var newItem = myMenu.addItem("Item 1");
newItem.triggered.connect(onTriggered);
```

Nevertheless is there a better way? Above I defined a custom function that happened to be named `onTriggered`, but it can be named anything, right? So this code piece doesn't make use of the built-in handler, that's why I'm wondering if there's a neater solution?

More importantly, later on I've noticed further problems with this approach: in a for loop, if there is a temporary variable used by the handler, things don't work any more:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i ++) {
    var info = myArray[i];
    var newItem = myMenu.addItem("Item " + i);
    newItem.triggered.connect(function() {
        console.log(info);
    });
}
```

Here you'll see that console prints the *last* `info` in `myArray` for all added menu items when triggered. How can I properly set up independent handlers for each individual menu item?

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898526/qml-lambda-function-works-unexpectedly/28900786#28900786

Comment: As for the rest - that is the way to go in QML. It is simple and easy enough. What would intrinsic handlers do for you? Save you typing a few characters at the cost of losing flexibility. You can, if you really want, make your items automatically connect to a predetermined handler, all you need to provide to the item is a reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the comments, you can easily make it "easier":

```
Menu {
    id: myMenu

    function add(text, handler) {
        var newItem = addItem(text)
        newItem.triggered.connect(handler)
    }
}
```

And there you have it, problem solved, now you can simply `myMeny.add("Item 1", onTriggered)`

As for the result you get in the loop and functor, that's because of JS's scoping rules. Check the linked answer for details how to work around that.

> So this code piece doesn't make use of the built-in handler

Don't think of `onSignal` as a handler, it is just a hook to attach a handler. Think of it as the declarative connection syntax. Sure, you can also use the `Connection` element in declarative, but it only makes sense when the situation actually merits it.

I think this confusion stems from some other language / framework which does generate handler methods for you. A `onSignal` is different from `function onSignal() { expression }` - the latter is a handler function, the former is handler hook, which just connects the signal to the bound `expression.eval()`. The Qt documentation too refers to `onSignal` as a handler, which IMO is technically and conceptually wrong, since the handler is the code which gets executed, the handler is whatever you bind to `onSignal`.

So you can rest easy, the code you are worried about does not result in any sort of redundancy or inefficiency and doesn't leave anything unused and is in fact the correct way to do things in QML.

All that being said, you **can** have "built in handlers", but it is a very different thing:

```
// SomeItem.qml
Item {
    signal someSignal
    onSomeSignal: console.log("I am a built in handler")
}

// main.qml
SomeItem {
    onSomeSignal: console.log("I am another handler")
    Component.onCompleted: {
        someSignal.connect(function(){console.log("Yet another handler")})
        someSignal()
    }
}
```

And the output in the console will say:

```
qml: I am a built in handler
qml: I am another handler
qml: Yet another handler
```

As you see, it not really a handler, but a connection hook. There is no shadowing, no "replacing / not using the built in handler", there is just a signal with 3 connections to the evaluation of three expressions.

Using `signal.connect()` with a named function does come with one advantage, you can later `signal.disconnect(namedFunction)` if you need to remove a built in or another handler. I am not sure if you can do this if you use `onSignal: expr` since you don't have a way to reference that anonymous expression. Note that if you use `onSignal: namedFunction()` this will not work, you will not be able to `signal.disconnect(namedFunction)` because the signal is not directly connected to that function, but to an anonymous expression invoking it.

Comment: It's very helpful! Thank you for taking the time to write this, I'm sure more beginners like me will find this a great read.